# in iOS, how can I switch between text fields in two cells?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitextfield

I have an app using a TableView of custom cells, each containing a textField. When the user taps a cell, I want to put the corresponding textField into edit mode. If another cell's textField is already in edit mode, I need to have it resignFirstResponder so I can save its data and then make the new cell's textField become the FirstResponder. But when I call becomeFirstResponder on the new cell's textField, it returns a zero indicating failure. This seems like a messy way to handle it, but I haven't found anything better - yet.

Here's the full text of my TableViewController's files with a lot of clutter stripped out:

```
//  TEST_TVC.h
//  TVC_Test
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface TEST_TVC : UITableViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>
@end


//  TEST_TVC.m
//  TVC_Test
#import "TEST_TVC.h"
@interface TEST_TVC ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray * TestData;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UITextField * fieldBeingEdited;
@property (assign, nonatomic) NSInteger cellIndex;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UITableViewCell * cellContainingField;

@end

@implementation TEST_TVC

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Init data for testing the TableView
    self.TestData = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (int i=0; i<25; i++) {
        NSString * title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Field %d", i];
        NSArray * data = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:title, @"*", nil];
        [self.TestData addObject:data];
    }
    self.fieldBeingEdited = NULL;
    self.cellContainingField = NULL;
    self.cellIndex = -1;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return self.TestData.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Configure the cell...
    NSString *CellIdentifier = @"TVCell";
    NSString * titleText;
    NSString * detailText;
    NSString * detailPlaceholder = @"none";

    // Get the data for this row
    int rowNumber = indexPath.row;
    NSArray * cellData = self.TestData[rowNumber];
    titleText = cellData[0];
    detailText = cellData[1];
    //NSLog(@"cellForRow..., entered row=%d, titleText=%@, detailText=%@", rowNumber, titleText, detailText);

    // Retrieve a pre-built cell to fill in the blanks
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    UILabel * cellTitle = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:98];
    cellTitle.text = titleText;
    UITextField * cellDetail = (UITextField *)[cell viewWithTag:99];
    NSLog(@"cellForRow.. reusing cell with Title=%@ and Detail=%@", cellTitle.text, cellDetail.text);
    NSLog(@"cellForRow.. intended Title=%@, intended Detail=%@", titleText, detailText);
    if (cellDetail == NULL) {
        NSLog(@"cellForRow..; cellDetail = NULL *******************************************");
    }

    // Set default configuration of the cellData UITextField here, and make exceptions later
    cellDetail.placeholder = @"";
    cellDetail.text = @"";
    cellDetail.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
    cellDetail.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    cell.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

    // Configure the cell...
    // based on the data type of the cell's contents

    // Set the cell's editable textField
    if ( [detailText isEqualToString:@"*"] ) {
        cellDetail.text = @"";
        cellDetail.placeholder = detailPlaceholder;
    } else {
        cellDetail.text = detailText;
    }
    cellDetail.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeASCIICapable;
    cellDetail.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeWords;

    return cell;
}


#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    int rowNumber = indexPath.row;
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
    NSLog(@"didSelectRow.. entered; row=%d, cellData=%@", rowNumber, self.TestData[rowNumber]);
    // The selected cell contains a textField with content to be edited
    // If another cell's textField is currently being edited, save its data before proceding
    UITableViewCell * cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    UITextField * cellDetail = (UITextField *)[cell viewWithTag:99];
    NSLog(@"didSelectRow..: curently editing cell at [%p], selected cell at [%p]", self.fieldBeingEdited, cell);
    // if a textField is still in edit mode, show the Responder status of the cell and all in it
    if ( self.fieldBeingEdited != NULL ) {
        [self showCellResponderStatus:self.cellContainingField];
    }

    if ( self.fieldBeingEdited == NULL ) {
        NSLog(@"didSelectRow..: no field is being edited.");
    } else if ( cellDetail == self.fieldBeingEdited ) {
        // the cell selected is the same one being edited
        if ( ![self.fieldBeingEdited isFirstResponder] ) {
            // fieldBeingEdited is NOT the firstResponder. Try to make it the firstResponder.
            BOOL becameFirstResponder = [self.fieldBeingEdited becomeFirstResponder];
            NSLog(@"didSelectRow..: textField at [%p] returned %d from becomeFirstResponder.", self.fieldBeingEdited, becameFirstResponder);
            [self showCellResponderStatus:self.cellContainingField];
        }
    } else if ( cellDetail != self.fieldBeingEdited ) {
        // the cell selected is NOT the one being edited. Save the edited data and release the keyboard
        NSLog(@"didSelectRow..: field in cell with index=%d is being edited. Text=%@", self.cellIndex, self.fieldBeingEdited.text);
        BOOL resignedFirstResponder;
        [self showCellResponderStatus:self.cellContainingField];
        // This method call will log the responder status of this cell and all it is contained within
        //[self showViewHierarchy:self.fieldBeingEdited];
        resignedFirstResponder = [self.fieldBeingEdited resignFirstResponder];
        NSLog(@"didSelect..: resignFirstResponder on [%p] returned %d", self.fieldBeingEdited, resignedFirstResponder);
        //[self showViewHierarchy:self.fieldBeingEdited];
        if (resignedFirstResponder) {
            self.fieldBeingEdited = NULL;
            self.cellContainingField = NULL;
            self.cellIndex = -1; 
        }
    }

    // Enable the textField within the selected cell for in-place editing
    cellDetail.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    cellDetail.enabled = YES;
    BOOL becameFirstResponder = [cellDetail becomeFirstResponder];
    NSLog(@"didSelectRow..: becomeFirstResponder returned %d", becameFirstResponder);
    if ( becameFirstResponder ) {
        // Update all the references and indexes for the cell and textField being edited.
        self.fieldBeingEdited = cellDetail;
        self.cellContainingField = cell;
        self.cellIndex = rowNumber;
    }

    NSLog(@"didSelectRow.. exit; textFieldBeingEdited.text=%@, cellIndex=%d", self.fieldBeingEdited.text, self.cellIndex);

}

-(BOOL) textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    NSLog(@"textFieldShouldBeginEditing entered");
    NSLog(@"... returning YES");
    return YES;
}

-(void) textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    NSLog(@"textFieldDidEndEditing entered with text: %@, cellIndex=%d", textField.text, self.cellIndex);
    NSInteger cellIndex = self.cellIndex;

    NSMutableArray * cellData = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:self.TestData[cellIndex]];
    [cellData replaceObjectAtIndex:1 withObject:textField.text];
    [self.TestData replaceObjectAtIndex:cellIndex withObject:cellData];
    textField.enabled = NO;

    [self.tableView reloadData];
    if ( [textField isFirstResponder] ) {
        NSLog(@"EditFlight(466): textFieldDidEndEditing; textField IS STILL the firstresponder!");
    }
    NSLog(@"textFieldDidEndEditing exit; cellData=%@", cellData);
}

-(BOOL) textFieldShouldReturn: (UITextField *)textField
{
    NSLog(@"textFieldShouldReturn; textField.text=%@", textField.text);
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    BOOL resignedFirstResponder = [textField resignFirstResponder];
    NSLog(@"textFieldShouldReturn; resignFirstResponder returned %d",resignedFirstResponder);
    return YES;
}

-(void) showCellResponderStatus:(UITableViewCell*)cell
{
    NSLog(@"showCellResponderStatus entered");
    if ( [cell isFirstResponder] ) {
        NSLog(@"cell at [%p] IS first responder", cell);
    }else{
        NSLog(@"cell at [%p] IS NOT first responder", cell);
    }
    NSArray * cellSubViews = [[cell contentView] subviews];
    for ( UIView* uiv in cellSubViews ) {
        if ( [uiv isFirstResponder ]) {
            NSLog(@"subview at [%p] is a %@ and IS first responder", uiv, uiv.class);
        } else {
            NSLog(@"subview at [%p] is a %@ and IS NOT first responder", uiv, uiv.class);
        }
    }
}

-(void) showViewHierarchy:(UIView*) uiv
{
    NSLog(@"View Hierarchy");
    while (uiv != NULL) {
        BOOL isfirst = [uiv isFirstResponder];
        NSLog(@"view at [%p] is a %@, isFirstResponder=%d", uiv, uiv.class, isfirst);
        uiv = uiv.superview;
    }
    NSLog(@"view at [%p] is a %@", uiv, uiv.class);
    NSLog(@"End of view hierarchy");
}

@end
```

Comment: edit formatting to emphase what is code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a much simpler approach. In `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` store a reference to the current cell's UITextField. Then you can set it as first responder, deal with edits, etc.

When you tap on a new cell to select it, the delegate first receives a `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath`. Here you can use your UITextField reference can resign first responder, save any necessary state, etc. Then `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath` is called on the new cell and you're good to go. So something like the following:

**Edit: added additional code**

```
// Code additions to Xcode's Master-Detail application template

// Use dynamic prototypes for table cells, custom cell class follows:

// MyCell.h
// Property is auto-synthesized, so there is nothing to see in MyCell.m

@interface MyCell : UITableViewCell
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UITextField *tf;
@end



// MasterViewController.m

@interface MasterViewController () {
  NSMutableArray *_objects;
}
@property (nonatomic, weak) UITextField *selectedField;
@end


// this method is called when a cell is DE-selected
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
      [self.selectedField resignFirstResponder];
      // save state, etc if necessary
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    MyCell * cell = (MyCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    self.selectedField = cell.tf; // cell.tf is a UITextField property defined on MyCell
    [self.selectedField becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

Comment: I believe this is exactly what I'm doing. In my code (in the question), there is a private property named fieldBeingEdited, which is the reference you suggest. My problem occurs when attempting to make the newly-selected cell's textField becomeFirstResponder - it won't.

Comment: Yes, sorry if my answer is not clear. My main point is that rather than trying to do all the logic in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, I've broken it up into two steps in 'didDeselectRow...` and 'didSelectRow...`. My guess is that there is some logic error in your function and rather than trying to debug a large, complicated method, I would recommend instead writing two simple methods. Anyway, I have a working project that allows you to switch cells, let me know if you'd like and I will edit my answer to show more of the code.

Comment: I would love to see a working example. And my puzzlement from your answer is that you appear to have two methods with identical names - how can that be? Maybe your code will clear it up.

Comment: Check the listing again. The methods are didSelect and did-DE-select.

Answer (score 0):

You might ask the first `textfield` if it is the `firstResponder` and then change that, before setting the second as `firstResponder`:

```
if ([textfield isEditing]) {
            [textfield resignFirstResponder];
}
```

But first `textField` will ask it´s delegate before resigning as a first responder by calling:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
}
```

so check why you are returning `NO` if you have implemented this method.

Comment: I am calling resignFirstResponder on the first textField and have confirmed that it returned a 1 before calling becomeFirstResponder on the second textField. The documentation says the new textField must be in the Responder Chain, and I assume it is since it's a textField in a different cell of the same TableView.

Comment: @A.Baker - You can tell the second textField to become the responder by calling [textfield becomeFirstResponder]; You can also ask for the nextResponder. All this is gotten by checking out the UIResponder class, which the textfield inherits from.

Comment: @A.Baker - You might solve this by resigning all the textfields and then send becomeFirstResponder to the one selected. There is one more important thing to keep in mind, when you recycle the UITableViewCells, that you are not adding a new textField on top of a previous one, from the last cell that UITableViewCells was used for.

Comment: @A.Baker - Also make sure that the textField editAble property is set to YES if you created it programmatically.

Comment: I believe I've covered all the bases except for resigning First Responder on ALL textFields. That will take some extra work to keep a list of all the textFields in the reusable cell list for the TableView. Before I do that though, when I tell the current textField to resignFirstResponder, does some other control automatically become the FirstResponder? If so, how do I find it and get it to resign so I can make the textField of my choice become FirstResponder? Obviously the responder chain is still mysterious to me, so please help me out.

Comment: Just a bit of clarification. My TableView contains one prototype dynamic cell. It has the custom style and contains a single UILable for a title and a UITextField for editable data. This was configured in the storyboard, so I'm not adding or removing any components programmatically. I am, however, enabling and disabling components programmatically. Until a user selects a cell, the textField will not respond to user interactions. When the user selects the cell, I enable the textField, save a reference so I'll know which textField is being edited, and then the textField to becomeFirstResponder.

Comment: @A.Baker - Use tags to easily get all textfields in one loop, by looking for views with certain tag (which you set in storyboard). The cells are reused automatically by the tableview regardless of whether they are created programmatically or in Storyboard, so make sure that cells are reset before reuse. You can ask a cell for all its subviews when selected, just to verify this.

Comment: I don't seem to be making any progress. The explanation online says that something else must be the firstResponder, but I've checked every other view in the view hierarchy with no luck. The problem is only when I resign FirstResponder with one textField and try to become FirstResponder with a textField in a different TableViewCell.

Comment: @A.Baker - It´s hard for me to comment without the code. If you like you can send me the code in private: hannessv@simnet.is

Comment: I'll clean up to code to remove a lot of distractions and will post it this weekend. Thanks for hanging in there with me.

Comment: Here is a section of my didSelectRowAtIndexPath method that attempts to make a new textField the firstResponder:

    cellDetail.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    cellDetail.enabled = YES;
    BOOL becameFirstResponder = [cellDetail becomeFirstResponder];
    NSLog(@"didSelectRow..: becomeFirstResponder returned %d", becameFirstResponder);
    if ( becameFirstResponder ) {
        // Update all the references and indexes for the cell and textField being edited.
        self.fieldBeingEdited = cellDetail;
        self.cellContainingField = cell;
        self.cellIndex = rowNumber;
    }

Comment: I apologize for the awful formatting. I just pasted some code directly from Xcode into the comment block.

Comment: @A.Baker I am sorry but I can´t find a problem from the code snippet. To problem solve I recommend you start by creating only one sell and get everything working and then go onto two and finally cell that scroll offscreen and onscreen. If you can´t get it working for one cell then try with a simple view with two text fields.

Comment: Thanks. I wanted to post a larger code snippet, but there apparently isn't a way to do that here. I appreciate your advice.

Comment: I found out how to edit my question and add the code there. So all the code for the .h and .m files of my TableViewController is there. I tried to strip out all the irrelevant stuff, and it still behaves like before.

Comment: @A.Baker You forgot to add the code for the TableViewCell: TVCell

Comment: I have no code specifically for the TVCell. It's defined in a storyboard: one prototype cell in the TableView. The cell is a custom format, with one Label and one textField. These two items have tags of 98 and 99 respectively. The cell has userInteraction enabled, but the textField has userInteraction disabled. The cell's identifier is TVCell.

Answer (score 0):

You may also use an open source as BSKeyboardControls. It also includes other keyboard-textfield relationship that may help you in the procces.
s
Link for it: https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/bskeyboardcontrols

Comment: Thanks for the advice and link. I want to be able to select cells in any order, not just next and previous, but if I can't find a way to make this work, I'll be back to the BSKeyboardControls.